# Extend Exception in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got error Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in ....\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233

I create a class called My_Exceptions in application/core/My_Exception.php
Basically, I want to get email when user gets error from my site.

```
<?php
class My_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions{
    var $CI="";
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }
    function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
{
    $heading = "404 Page My Not Found";
    $message = "The page you requested was not found.";

    // By default we log this, but allow a dev to skip it
    if ($log_error)
    {
        log_message('error', '404 Page Not Found --> '.$page);
    }

    //Email to Developer
    $this->CI->load->library('email');
    $uri = $this->CI->uri->uri_string();  
    $this->CI->email->from('error-donotreply@YOURAPP.com', 'APP Error');
    $this->CI->email->to('youremail@example.org');
    $this->CI->email->subject('APP Error [severity: '.$severity.']');
    $this->CI->email->message("Page not Found. From URL: ".$uri);
    $this->CI->email->send();

    echo $this->show_error($heading, $message, 'error_404', 404);
    exit;
}
}
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Exceptions class is loaded BEFORE the main CI_Controller.

This means when an error occurs - you cannot use CI to send an email, because "$this->CI" does not exist.

Your options are to either use the native PHP to send the email, or what I do; automatically email yourself the error logs from the day before (using a CRON job). That way you can review all the errors once a day.

Comment: It seems pretty crazy to get an email for *every* 404 that gets generated, emailing or manually reviewing the daily log makes more sense (I can understand not wanting to create cron jobs). Native `mail()` should be just fine, it's not a big deal when you're just emailing yourself.

Comment: The OP's code is written into the `show_404` function, but you may be right. In that case, I'd say it's even more insane to send an individual email for every error because there will be even more. Unless you really want your inbox blowing up like crazy... A single page load can generate *tons* of 404's (missing images for example).

Comment: Not just for 404 error. I will add to another error handler. 404 is easy to test on my localhost. 

Thanks, I am gonna try PHP native.

Answer (score 4):

I know you ahve accepted an answer but an alternative method would be to extend CI log class.

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * MY_Log Class
 *
 * This library extends the native Log library.
 * It adds the function to have the log messages being emailed when they have been outputted to the log file.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage      Libraries
 * @category        Logging
 * @author      Johan Steen
 * @link        http://wpstorm.net/
 */
class MY_Log extends CI_Log {
    private $_reporting_email = 'test@me.com';
    private $_subject = 'CI Logger';

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @access  public
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Write Log File
     *
     * Calls the native write_log() method and then sends an email if a log message was generated.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  the error level
     * @param   string  the error message
     * @param   bool    whether the error is a native PHP error
     * @return  bool
     */
    function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE) {
        $result = parent::write_log($level, $msg, $php_error);

        if ($result == TRUE && strtoupper($level) == 'ERROR') {
            $message = "An error occurred: \n\n";
            $message .= $level.' - '.date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> '.$msg."\n";

            $to = $this->_reporting_email;
            $subject = $this->_subject;
            $headers = 'From: Example Name <no-reply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n';

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is another alternative. Thanks